# How to launch commands in Emacs via global Hotkey in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, hotkeys

I'm using Emacs org-mode to create and manage notes and tasks and I'd like to be able to create a new element in org-mode "from anywhere" in Windows 7 (no matter if I am working in MS Office or any other application).

Which possibilities are there to create customized global hotkeys, so that I can press a certain command "anywhere" in Windows which activates Emacs (if it is already open) or opens it and executes a certain command in emacs?

It would be great (but is not absolutely necessarry) if this would be possible without extra software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this which is extra software, but it's very useful, because you can use it to automate all sorts of other things too on your computer, besides using it for controlling emacs.